# ImageMagick max blurring parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick to blur any inappropriate image that a user would upload, selected with Google Cloud Vision :

```js
 await exec(`convert "${tempLocalFile}" -channel RGBA -blur 0x8 "${tempLocalFile}.jpeg"`);
```

The examples that I found online proposed `0x8` as a parameter value, but when I tested it, it came up that the blur effect was not enough and we could still see things that shouldn't be seen.

I would like the resulting picture to be completely blurred so that we cannot distinguish anything.

What would be the max parameter to get a full blurred picture as a result?

Comment: Why have you added -channel rgba?  Do you need to blur the alpha channel?  There is no limit on the blur value and it would depend upon the image as to what value you would need. There is no universal formula or value.

Comment: What do you mean by there's no limit on the blur value ? Isn't there a value for which we are sure that not matter what the image is, everything will be so blurry that we would't recognize any shape ? I'm comparing that to the image editing software where you can put a gaussian blur with the maximum position of the selector as a value, so that we can't recognize anything

Comment: I meant there is no upper limit on the blur value. You can blur as much as you want. But there is no universal algorithm to tell you how much you need to blur your image so that it is not recognizable. It depends upon the size of the objects in your scene.

Comment: Does this mean that my problem has no solution ? I always find the values `0x8` in code samples when it comes to ImageMagick. It also is the value given as an example in the official website https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/blur_montage.jpg

Comment: The needed value is image dependent. You have to decide when it it blurry enough for you. There is no universal solution that I know. Perhaps it can be solved by AI / Deep Learning.

Comment: Larger images probably need larger amounts of blurring. Likewise, large object in the image need more blurring than small objects. Experimentation may provide a solution for you.

Comment: But then, if there are no universal algorithm, what kind of algorithm use editing software like photoshop, where they give you a selector to increase the radius and enventually blur any image ?

Comment: They just stop at some point in value at a large amount. They have no universal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

##### Answer

Resize the image before applying the blur:

```
await exec(`convert "${tempLocalFile}" -channel RGBA -resize 100x100 -blur 0x8 "${tempLocalFile}"`);
```

##### Explanation

The value `-blur 0x8` means you are blurring with a radius of `0` and a sigma of `8`, which "can be thought of as an approximation of just how much your want the image to 'spread' or blur, in pixels" ([source](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/)). These values are absolute, not relative to the image size. Therefore a sigma of 8 pixels has a stronger effect on images with smaller dimensions.

It should be noted that `-resize 100x100` resizes your image while maintaining its aspect ratio ([source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-resizing-images-with-imagemagick#resize-to-specific-dimensions-and-keep-aspect-ratio)).